# How to save paints aswell as that background into sdcars

Tags: android, android-sdcard

My Android application is supposed to save paints and a background image on my device's SD Card. I am using the method below inside my view class, but for some reason the SD Card is only saving the paints. I can't figure out why the background image isn't saving.

```
File myDir=new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is where I'm attempting to save the background, but it isn't working. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.